# can't create phonertc client

Tags: javascript, ios, sockets, cordova, phonertc

I found very good project [on Github](https://github.com/alongubkin/phonertc/wiki/Getting-Started), but I can not understand all of it.

I installed a signaling server (socket.io) and a turn server. I'm trying to make an app for IOS and I'm using code like:

```
<video height="300" id="localVideo"></video>
<video id="remotesVideos"></video>

<script type="text/javascript">
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

  function onDeviceReady() {
    var phonertc = cordova.require('com.dooble.phonertc.PhoneRTC');
    var socket = io('http://mysait.com:3000');

    socket.on("connect", function() {
      socket.emit("join", "myroom");
      socket.on("message", function(message) {
        console.log("GOT MESSAGE:");
        message.payload.sdp = message.payload.sdp.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");

        // when a message is received from the signaling server,
        // notify the PhoneRTC plugin.
        phonertc.receiveMessage(message.payload);
      });
    });

    socket.on('connect',function() {
      alert ('is connect!');
    });

    phonertc.call({
      isInitator: true, // Caller or callee?
      turn: {
        host: 'turn:mysait.com:3478',
        username: 'test',
        password: 'test'
      },
      sendMessageCallback: function (data) {
        // PhoneRTC wants to send a message to your target, use
        // your signaling server here to send the message.
        console.log(data);
        socket.emit("message", data);
      },
      answerCallback: function () {
        alert('Callee answered!');
      },
      disconnectCallback: function () {
        alert('Call disconnected!');
      },
      video: {  // Remove this property if you don't want video chat
        localVideo: document.getElementById('localVideo'),
        remoteVideo: document.getElementById('remoteVideo')
      }
    });
  }
</script>
```

I have an alert when connection is made to server, but I don't see local and remote video. Can someone suggest what could be wrong? Can you send me example of client-side, I can't find it [here](https://github.com/alongubkin/phonertc/tree/master/demo/client).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is a very old version of the demo app. The correct link is:
https://github.com/alongubkin/phonertc/tree/master/demo

Comment: and i need copy all files from dir app to my phonegap project?

Comment: You should probably just re-clone the project

Comment: like this git clone  MyTest https://github.com/alongubkin/phonertc.git in new cordova project?